# Graph Chart.js dropdown menu - chart rendering

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I used chart.js to plot the data. Now, after selecting from the dropdown, I always want to display the relevant line (using the updateChartType function).

Unfortunately, I only see two points in the graph. Can someone please advise me where the mistake is, please?

My demo is here - [http://jsfiddle.net/ondra15/chqa30sf/55/]

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the `options` object in your `updateChartType` function

```
function updateChartType() {
  myChart.destroy();
  myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: options2.data,
    options: options2.options //<--- this line
  });
  myChart.getDatasetMeta(document.getElementById("chartType").value).hidden = false;
};
```

if you want the dropdown to toggle between different datasets, you can use the following:

You don't need to create a new chart, you can simply update the current one, but
**you need to call `chart.update()`**

```
function updateChartType() {
  const val = document.getElementById("chartType").value
  for (const i in myChart.data.datasets) {
    if (i == val) myChart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden = false;
    else myChart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden = true;
  }
  myChart.update();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now the problem is that after switching to dropdown, a new line (new curve) will not be displayed. That's not right. Can I still ask for help?

Comment: What exactly do you want the dropdown to do? Put that in your question and I'll help :)

Comment: If you select option # 2 or # 3 in the listbox, then with value = "1 | 2" I want to display a curve (course) in the graph. Except for the first curve, the remaining curves are hidden at the beginning.

The first curve is already displayed in the graph.

The curve display is using `myChart.getDatasetMeta(document.getElementById("chartType").value).hidden = false;`

Comment: If I understood you right, my edited answer should help you

Comment: Many thanks for the adjustment, everything is fine :-) I will try further adjustments to the graph